# react-to-print Page numbers Display

Tags: react-to-print

```
const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
    content: () => currentRef,
    pageStyle: `
    @page {
        size: auto;
        margin: 11mm 17mm 17mm 17mm;

        @top-right-corner {
            content: "Page " counter(page);
          }
}`,
    documentTitle: "Statement"  
  });
```

This is my code and how can i show page number in my print pdf page? many times i try but it doesn't work some one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the selector you have used is the issue here.
I recommend using the `@top-right` selector or `@bottom-right` selector instead of `@top-right-corner` selector.